# TeamCity + git-teamcity plugin: ParseException

Tags: java, git, teamcity

Alright, I've trying to set up a TeamCity server the past few hours, but this as really gotten me stuck. I've got everything working, agents are running, plugin is installed, but when I run the build process it instantly crashes with the following log error:

```
Error collecting changes for VCS root 'git@github.com:chrisjowen/nLess.git:master' #1  
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
"Mon Nov 16 15:01:08 2009 +0100"
```

We already have a TeamCity setup on a remote server, but I didn't set it up myself. I just want to be able to do the same thing personally, because I'd like to see if we can benefit from this at work.

I use the exact same TeamCity configuration as the remote one, and I updated git to the latest version.

The date you see is the date of the last commit on the master branch on the github repository, so it must be something in the VCS plugin. Anyone encounter this? Or even better, anyone know what I should do to solve this?

Additional info:
Windows XP Professional (32 bit), English
TeamCity Professional Version 4.5.5 (build 9103)
git-teamcity plugin available here: http://github.com/chrisortman/git-teamcity

---

Use http://github.com/petemounce/git-teamcity, this fork fixes the issue I had. The dateformat didn't specify a locale, so it used the default. This fork explicitly sets the US locale, which works when you're using a different locale (mine was set to nl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it myself. Apparently, even if windows is set to English, my JRE is set to Dutch. I'll have to figure out why that is now ;-)